# Exporting functions from a C# class library

Tags: c#, c++, dll, export

How would I export functions defined in a C# class library, while enabling them to be imported to and called from an unmanaged C++ application/DLL ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you can't just export functions as you would in a classic .dll, as .NET .dll's aren't really .dll's at all. Your only three options are:

1. Use managed C++
2. Expose your C# classes as COM objects and consume them from your C++ code
3. [Host the .NET runtime in your C++ project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx) and interact with your C# classes through that.

Answer (score 2):

Your C++ Apllication would have to start by hosting the CLR. There is nothing special required from the .NET DLL.

Answer (score 1):

You would not. Not supported. You can pretty much only export COM objects from a C# class librarly.

Comment: +1 - COM interop is a fairly standard technique for calling managed code from an unmanaged app.

Answer (score 1):

You could also make a C++ wrapper for your C# library - a simple Managed C++ DLL that would import .NET methods and export them natively. This adds an additional layer, but it might be useful if C# library is a must have.

Another option is to tweak the compiled assembly to export the functions. A C# compiler cannot do this, but it takes a slight change of MSIL code to get the things done.
Have a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DllExport.aspx?msg=2657379) - there're some links on how the stuff works, and a tool to automate it (though I haven't tried it myself).

Comment: A C# library isn't a requirement - As a matter of fact, I was considering to use managed C++ instead. I can't use the CLI with my primary application but I can use it to write my library. How would that change the scenario ?

Comment: In this case, you should use Managed C++ - just to avoid unnecessary hacking.