# C++ Pass C# object

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am making a game engine and would like the scripts to be in C# but the back end to be in c++. I would like in c# to do:

```
public class Player: Engine.Object{//snip}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Engine.AddObject(new Player());
}

public static class Engine
{
    [DLLImport("cgameengine.dll")]
    private static void INTERNAL_ADD_OBJECT(Engine.Object obj);
    public static void AddObject(Engine.Object obj)
    { INTERNAL_ADD_OBJECT(obj);}
}
```

How would I define the method in c++?
Note every frame I want to run `Player.Update();`
I have looked at multiple questions on this topic and none of then gave a concise answer. Additionally how would I store the objects in the c++ dll?

Comment: You might try passing C# method and data structure to the Dll function as separate arguments.  It’s definitely possible to invoke c# method reference as c-function pointers from a DLL created with a c++ compiler.  The same goes for structures.

Comment: Thank you. I will look at that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944539/wrapping-managed-code-for-unmanaged-use/9945259#9945259

Comment: @BillMoore thank you. System.Action is equivalent to void(*updateFunction)();